# Update column with average values in same table using JOIN - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregate-functions, average

I have following table

```
[Table_01]
ID  |   Name    |   Profit  |   AvgProfit
------------------------------------------
1   |   Donald  |   1001    |   
2   |   Hillary |   101     |   
3   |   Barack  |   11      |   
4   |   Bernie  |   1       |   
1   |   Donald  |   1002    |   
2   |   Hillary |   102     |   
3   |   Barack  |   12      |   
4   |   Bernie  |   2       |   
1   |   Donald  |   1003    |   
2   |   Hillary |   103     |   
3   |   Barack  |   13      |   
4   |   Bernie  |   3       |
```

I need to add average Profit value for each person.

Result after UPDATE should be:

```
[Table_01]
ID  |   Name    |   Profit  |   AvgProfit
------------------------------------------
1   |   Donald  |   1001    |   1002
2   |   Hillary |   101     |   102
3   |   Barack  |   11      |   12
4   |   Bernie  |   1       |   1
1   |   Donald  |   1002    |   1002
2   |   Hillary |   102     |   102
3   |   Barack  |   12      |   12
4   |   Bernie  |   2       |   1
1   |   Donald  |   1003    |   1002
2   |   Hillary |   103     |   102
3   |   Barack  |   13      |   12
4   |   Bernie  |   3       |   1
```

I do get average values using:

```
SELECT z1.*, AVG(Profit) OVER(PARTITION BY Name) AVERAGE
    FROM Table_01 z1
    order by Name
```

For update I've tried multiple JOIN clauses with no success.
I get various errors: using AGGREGATE in JOIN and invalid object names.

This one works in Oracle, i suppose.

```
UPDATE Table_01 z1 
SET z1.AvgSecs = (SELECT AVG(Profit) 
                 FROM Table_01
                 WHERE Name = z1.Name)
```

What is the syntax used in Microsoft SQL Server 2014?

### QUESTION 2

I have another table which i need to update

```
[Table_02]
Name    |   AvgProfit                   Name    |   AvgProfit
---------------------   UPDATE -->      ---------------------
Donald  |                               Donald  |   1002
Hillary |                               Hillary |   102
Barack  |                               Barack  |   12
Bernie  |                               Bernie  |   1
```

I wonder if this works:

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.AvgProfit = t1.AvgProfit
FROM Table_02 t2
    join Table_01 t1 
    ON   t1.Name = t2.Name
```

"Name" is a Unique value

Great thanks for all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CTE for the first update:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Id, AVG(Profit) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) As AvgProfit
    FROM Table_01
)

UPDATE T1
SET AvgProfit = CTE.AvgProfit
FROM Table_01 T1 
INNER JOIN CTE ON(T1.Id = CTE.Id)
```

As for your second question - The answer is yes.

Comment: Works like the train toilet.

Comment: I tried to Google but did not find an easy way to get AVG result where result is rounded to closest integer. From the box it rounds down.

Comment: Not so sure if the train toilet works well in your country... about the round down part I'll have to check.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1 :

```
 UPDATE Table_01 SET AvgProfit = _AvgProfit FROM
 (SELECT ID , AVG(Profit) _AvgProfit FROM Table_01 GROUP BY ID )
 A WHERE A.ID = Table_01.ID
```

Question 2 :

```
UPDATE Table_02 SET Table_02.AvgProfit = t1.AvgProfit 
FROM Table_01 t1 WHERE t1.Name = Table_02.Name
```

Comment: Thanks Mansoor. I tried something similar before and did not get it. I prefer Zohar's answer because I'm going to get familiar with CTE's. One question: in  _AvgProfit  what does underscore present, is it part of the syntax or just a name you chose?

Comment: @Kaptah Just name I used.I think you previously use alias name in update table.So you remove then check